# activating Eclipse hot-keys ? From time to time, Ctrl + key stops working, as F3 etc.

Tags: eclipse

I probably hit a shortcut de activating hot keys. How to activate them again ?

I found issues about people having bugs but I nothing I saw seems related.

Right now, restarting eclipse solves it but it takes tiiime  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Eclipse where the hot keys stop working

[Bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385278)

> I am also facing a lot of problems regarding the keyboard shortcuts.
>   The issue is intermittent and all of a sudden most of the key board
>   shortcuts(specifically f3, ctrl+D, ctrl+O ) stop working unless I
>   restart my IDE.

Comment: I have discovered that most of the time, clicking the project explorer and then clicking the editor again fixes the issue temporarily